# How to do update in Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table in Hive I want update the value in one column. I know Hive will not support row level update. There any other way achieve this?

If so pls share the query with me.

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

hive supports insert,update and delete from `hive0.14` or

otherwise use `case` statements to achieve your update

for example if col3 needs to be udpated

```
Insert overwrite table tablename
select col1,col2,
case when condition then value else value end as col3 
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Hive version 0.14.0: INSERT VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE are now available with full ACID support

UPDATE Syntax:

`UPDATE tablename SET column = value [, column = value ...] [WHERE expression]`